# What are the key dimensions of the new IDA docking ports on the ISS?

Tags: iss, docking-port

I'm building a 3D model of the power and propulsion module of the Lunar Gateway, and I'm trying to establish a few dimensions so it's easier to make it accurate. It seems from [the artwork](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/ppe-gateway-2024_00012.png) that it uses an International Docking Adapter.

[image: 3d rendering of the power and propulsion module showing docking port and overall structure]
<sub>Credit:NASA</sub>

I have been looking for some reference for the diameters of parts of the IDA that I can more usefully use to scale the rest. The [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Docking_Adapter) mentions an external diameter of 160 cm, but it isn't clear to me where that is measured. The thing that seems like it would be really useful would be the dimensions of that metal ring where another similar ring has to lock into place. That definitely has to be a super standard size. It would also be nice to know the diameter of the opening in the middle in the image below, which is part of the Wikipedia article, and was taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/Z2qtIfuoyig) made by NASA Johnson SFC.

[image]

And maybe I'll just add that it very much looks like someone in NASA made that awesome 3D model of it in the first image above, as the credit for it is just 'NASA'. Which means it should be public domain, and I could just use it, if I could get my hands on it. I looked in the wonderful [3d Resources](https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/) collection NASA has online, but it isn't there. So if anyone has a tip for how I might reach that person, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For stuff made at NASA to pass into public domain, it needs to go through “Export Control”. This is a rather long, somewhat inconvenient process. It is especially hard when the item in question relates to in-progress development that has contractors’ IP and competition for contracts in the mix. There will likely eventually be a public 3D model for this. Keep in mind this render here pictures only the NASA reference model of the PPE, not the final design as built by the contractor.

Comment: That's interesting @CourageousPotato, thanks for that. The model is for public education purposes and doesn't need to be exact. That model is plenty, even if there are changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the info you seek is in the [International Docking Standard](http://www.internationaldockingstandard.com/download/IDSS_IDD_Revision_E_TAGGED.pdf).

[image]

Dimensions are in millimeters.

Comment: That's perfect. It has engineering drawings I can use to recreate key components exactly. Thanks.